# Trying to purchase the correct handlebar faceplate bolt in advance for Schwinn S2713TR

Tags: parts

My son has a Schwinn mountain bicycle and has lost one of the bolts to the faceplate that clamps the handlebar to the stem.

Now I dealing with this by phone, and I'd like to purchase a replacement on my way home.  But a trip home to unscrew the remaining bolt and then go to the hardware store to get a replacement can't really be done in one day before the store's closing.

Is there a standard part that typically used for this application that I can buy on the way home without having a sample to match?

Its a Schwinn Traverse 26 inch mountain bike model S2713TR with two sunken Allen head bolts holding the faceplate, one of which is missing

Comment: If there's anyone at home you can get an estimate if the length (maybe even without unscrewing) and buy a both M5 and M6 in that length or the next step up (see also my comment on Batman's answer).

Answer (score 2):

You really need to take the remaining bolt to the hardware store and get them to match something with the appropriate length and thread pitch.

This isn't a standard length or size, but its likely M5 or M6 with length somewhere between 15-25 mm. You'd probably end up buying at least 6-8 packs of bolts to find the right one without measuring the existing one.

Comment: I reckon a bag of M5x25 and a bag of M6x25 would be worth gambling on. These (as you say) are the most likely diameters and pitch isn't an issue unless you're *very* unlucky. There's a chance they'll be too long but they're unlikely to be too short and generally these screws can stick out the back.

Comment: The alternative is likely wait a day to remove the bolt, take it to the hardware store tomorrow and then just get the right bolt the first time. Given that this is a BSO, the risk of it being something else is higher than most quality bikes.

Comment: 2 bolt faceplates are never M5, and may be 8x1.25.